# Whiskering approach to strict 2-categories: literature reference needed

Tags: ct.category-theory, 2-categories

I am familiar with the nLab web page that nicely lays out the axioms needed to define strict 2-categories using whiskering as opposed to horizontal composition of 2-cells.  However, I am old fashioned and, when writing an article, would prefer to use a journal reference over a web URL reference.

Does anyone know of a published article that goes over the same material as the following page?

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/strict+2-category

Unfortunately that page gives no references.

Comment: In a comment, since this is not strictly (pun intended) what you are asking for: it has not yet been recorded in this thread that **strict 2-categories 'can be simulated by'  bicategories for which all 2-cells in the coherence axioms for bicategories are identities**. This well-known connection enlarges the pool of citable published references: you can choose one of the publications on bicategories, and note the connection via identity coherence cells. Naming a publication seems too much of a statement. There are more than one citable ones.@Matt Brinn

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The formal laws for defining 2-categories along these lines were first spelled out by Godement:

- Roger Godement, *Topologie algébrique et theorie des faisceaux*, Hermann, Paris, 1958.

See the "five rules of functorial calculus" given in Appendix 1. Indeed, the horizontal composition of 2-cells is sometimes called the Godement product, and is defined in terms of whiskerings and vertical composites.

Added: it should be said that Godement was speaking of the functorial calculus specifically of $\text{Cat}$, and did not introduce 2-categories as an abstract notion. My understanding is that it was Ehresmann who introduced 2-categories, as a special case of double categories.

The notion of *sesquicategory* formalizes a context in which one has vertical compositions and whiskerings, but one does not have the crucial interchange equation that was singled out by Godement. Thus, a 2-category is a sesquicategory in which the interchange equation is satisfied (giving the horizontal product). Such a development is indicated in

- Ross Street, *Categorical Structures*, in Handbook of Algebra Vol. 1 (ed. M. Hazewinkel), Elsevier Science, Amsterdam 1996. [(pdf)](http://maths.mq.edu.au/~street/45.pdf)

This would seem to give what you want.

Comment: @MattBrin Just added more information which may be more useful.

Comment: Might be worth adding these to the nLab page?

Comment: @Todd The Godement appendix seems to have what you advertise, except that the line above (V) seems to have a typo.  The Street exposition has the content and vocabulary without giving all the axioms.  I am not sure what is the interchange equation is that you say is missing from Street.  I would love something as complete and concise as the nLab page somewhere in print, but I guess it is too much to ask for.

Comment: Not missing from Street, but missing from sesquicategory. Given two 2-cells $\alpha: x \to y$ and $\beta: f \to g$ where $x, y: A \to B$ and $f, g: B \to C$, there are two choices in a sesquicategory for forming a horizontal composite $\beta \bullet \alpha: f x \to g y$, where $fx, gy: A \to C$. Both are the vertical composites of whiskerings; one is $(\beta y)(f\alpha)$, and the other is $(g\alpha)(\beta x)$. In a sesquicategory, they are generally unequal; the Godement interchange equation I meant says they are equal. So a 2-category is a sesquicategory satisfying this interchange equation.

Comment: (See page 535 of the Street reference.)

Comment: @MikeShulman, yes, quotable references would be nice.

Comment: @MikeShulman I have updated the nLab page to amplify this answer and give some references.